# where can I get cables for the Canon Mx310 (printer)

Tags: power-supply, printer, cable

A friend of mine gave me a printer/scanner because he could not print with it anymore. the point is this thing has been lying in the cellar for quite some time now and the cables are missing. that is the power cable for my power plug (there are foreign ones included) and more importantly the connection to the computer. I have googled around for a bit and tried to get to a hotline,but my problem is: 
*Where can I get those cables from?*

Can anyone help me get a clue where to find those, where to ask for something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That device uses a [standard USB A-B cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usb#USB_standard_connectors) which are available *everywhere* (perhaps even your corner pharmacy).

[image: USB Connectors]
"A" connector second from right
"B" connector last on the right

I can't tell from the [photographs](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/pixma_mx_series/pixma_mx310) whether it uses an [IEC C13/14 connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_connector), but if it does (or another IEC connector) they are very common and any store (computer store or even some hardware stores) that carries replacement power cables should have them.

[image: IEC C13]

You may also need [drivers](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/pixma_mx_series/pixma_mx310#DriversAndSoftware).

Comment: thanks i will check this at home and then mark it answered. However the power connector is another one. i will make a photo and post it here.